# Getting expiredate from table if equal or less then today SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

Some help would be appreciated.

I have a table `tblItem` with columns `ExpireDate` (`DateTime`), `AlertDays` (`Int`).

Each Item I insert has an `expiredate`, I want to be alert in x days before the `expiredate`.

I want to count all the items where `today + alertdays <= ExpireDate`.

I have the following code but it is causing an error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 48,Token in error = select ]

Please see my code:

```
internal static int getAlertDateExpire()
{
    SqlCeConnection con = ConectionAndData.Con;

    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        con.Open();

    int number = 0;

    string sqlCommand = "select count(*) from tblItem where (Getdate()+(select AlertDays from tblItem)) As today <= ExpireDate Order By ItemName ASC";

    SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(sqlCommand, con);

    try
    {
        number = (Int32)com.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help and want to share the answer.

```
(select count(*) from tblItem where dateadd(day,AlertDays,getdate()) >= ExpireDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not add days just using `+` use the `DATEADD` function:

```
select count(*) from tblItem where
 DATEADD(day, (select AlertDays from tblItem) ,Getdate()) 
 <= ExpireDate
```

Comment: Ashkan Mobayen: I tried your suggestion, and got this error message: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 50,Token in error = select ]

Comment: @PlazzaSele I updated the code. and by the way for getting the count you don't need `order by` clause

Comment: Ashkan: Thanks for your help, but still causing error: SqlCeException was caught: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 50,Token in error = select ]